# Spring @autowired do not work if all classes are not in the same package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have four packages:

1. com.spring.org

   Files: `HomeController.java`
2. com.spring.org.dao

   Files: `SubscriberDao.java` , `SubscriberDaoImpl.java`
3. com.spring.org.model

   Files: `Subscriber.java`
4. com.spring.org.service

   Files: `SubscriberService.java` , `SubscriberServiceImpl.java`

I put all my controller classes in **com.spring.org** package and others in different packages based on its type.  If I run my application I get this error message :

**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception**
*No qualifying bean of type [com.spring.org.service.SubscriberService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.....*

FYI: I am using autowired annoation in my Controller like following:

```
@Autowired
private SubscriberService subService;
```

But if I put all my classes and interfaces in **com.spring.org** package then my application works perfectly.

I have tried using these tags in my servlet-context.xml file to solve the problem, but still it did not work:

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org.**" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org.service" />
```

I also tried only this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org" />
```

You can see the code of my servlet-context.xml file here http://postimg.org/image/s6bnjccrn/

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Please let me know if you need to see any other files.

#### Update

My Code for SubscriberService :

```
@Service
public interface SubscriberService {

 public void addSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber);
 public void updateSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber);
 public Subscriber getSubscriberById(int subId);
 public List<Subscriber> listSubs();
 public int removeSubscriber(int subId);    

}
```

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.service.SubscriberService com.spring.org.HomeController.subService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spring.service.SubscriberService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)

#### Files

It would be very difficult to follow if I paste all my codes here, so I have upload my entire project here https://www.mediafire.com/?crxe7vt7uwyqwtl  . I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Problem may not be with scanning or configuration. Please post the code for `com.spring.org.service.SubscriberService` and it's implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please check the updated part of my question

Comment: For starters your base pacakge is wrong remove the `.**`. Also make sure that you put the annotation on the implementation NOT on the interface. If it is on the interface nothing is going to happen (such is the nature of annotations they aren't inherited from interfaces to classes!).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried removing .** but it did not work. And I have annotations in both my interfaces and implementation classes

Comment: pls add your whole code of SubscirberDao.java , SubscirberDaoImpl.java and HomeController.java so that we can understand the cause of the problem...

Comment: Your services aren't in `com.spring.org` but in `com.spring.services` so scannning `com.spring.org` doesn't include your services.

Comment: @M.Deinum I included this in my servlet-context.xml but still not working `<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org, com.spring.org.service" />`

Comment: @black_belt Read... Read agin.. As I mentioned your services are in `com.spring.services` **NOT** `com.spring.org.services` Check your packages in the actual project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your structure should be like this

**SubscriberService Interface**

```
package com.spring.org.service;

public interface SubscriberService {

}
```

**SubscriberServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.spring.org.service;

@Component
@Qualifier("Subscriber")
public class SubscriberServiceImpl implements SubscriberService {

}
```

‘SubscriberServiceImpl1’ is a component and it implements ‘SubscriberService’.

**SubscriberServiceImpl1.java**

```
package com.spring.org.service;

@Component
@Qualifier("Subscriber1")
public class SubscriberServiceImpl1 implements SubscriberService {

}
```

I setup a Spring context that scans both of these packages for beans marked with ‘@Component’.

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"/>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Subscriber")
    private SubscriberService subService;

}
```

refer from this **[link](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/)**.
hope this will help you....

**EDIT**

as per your package structure your ***SubscriberServiceImpl*** class is under package ***com.spring.org.service*** just change your base package with ***com.spring*** this will work for you

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have upload my entire project here mediafire.com/?crxe7vt7uwyqwtl . I am using Eclipse IDE. Could you please look through it once and tell me where I am doing the mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: your Service layer in different package its under com.spring.service package and you are specifying com.spring.org base package just change following line 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"/>
this will work for you...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are having multiple implementation of `SubscriberService` interface.

When you write following code:

```
@Autowired
private SubscriberService subService;
```

Spring will look for an implementation of `SubscriberService`, and since you would be having multiple implementation for it spring will not know which implementation to inject.

Solution to this is using `@Qualifier` to differentiate between different implementations.

For more and for a demo on `@Qualifier` visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm) link.

Alternatively if you're having a single implementation for `SubscriberService` make sure both the service and implementation fall under the packages you provide for scan in spring context.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only have one implementation of SubscriberService

Comment: Try qualifier anyway.

Comment: Please post the code of the class where you are autowiring `SubscriberService` and also its implementation class.

Comment: I have upload my entire project here  https://www.mediafire.com/?crxe7vt7uwyqwtl . I am using Eclipse IDE. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I looked into your code. The service layer does not fall under component scan, add a component scan for it or move it into com.spring.org

Comment: Thanks for taking time and looking into my code. I included this in my servlet-context.xml but still not working `<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org, com.spring.org.service" />` Am I supposed to put all my service files in the `com.spring.org` package and delete `com.spring.org.service`? Thanks a lot again

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after I moved my service files in `com.spring.org package`. But can't I have service classes and interfaces in a separate package

Answer (score 1):

Specify the base scan as follows and remove the annotation from interface and keep only in the implementation class e.g. @Service, @Repository, @Component, etc.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org"/>
```

**EDIT:**

I looked into your code.You have given your component scan as

But your SubscriberService.java is in the package com.spring.service. Kindly change the package to com.spring.org.service.

Comment: Also if possible try removing the below code <context:annotation-config /> as it is a subset of context:component-scan

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the base package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org"/>
```

I believe you should annotate the implementation class instead of the interface.

Comment: I have annotations in both my interfaces and implementation classes

Answer (score 0):

Try comma-separating the packages, like this:

```
<context:component-scan 
base-package="com.spring.org,com.spring.org.dao,com.spring.org.model,com.spring.org.service" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I just tried your code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Component on SubscriberServiceImpl.

Basically annotations like @Service, @Repository, @Component, etc. they all serve the same purpose:

> auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath
>   scanning.

From my experience I am always using @Service annotation on the interfaces or abstract classes and annotations like @Component and @Repository for their implementation. @Component annotation I am using on those classes which serves basic purposes, simple Spring beans, nothing more. @Repository annotation I am using in the DAO layer, for e.g. if I have to communicate to the database, have some transactions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put this tag in your XML (application context file):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.org"/>
```

To fix the expection you got you have to change this :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Subscriber")
private SubscriberService subService
```

because Spring searches for a bean of type `SubscriberService` (in your case), and if it finds such bean, it injects it to this method. If it finds two such beans you will get an Exception ( it is the same one in your stack trace).

f you don't want to use two annotations (the `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`) you can use `@Resource` to combine these two:

```
@Resource(name="redBean")
private SubscriberService subService
```